# Remove "|" from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't have access to edit the html , so is there a way with css to remove the " | " between each a tag below . If not with css possibly javascript or jquery

```
<span class="reportnavigation">
    <span class="reportnavigationheader">
        Go To Week: 
    </span>
    <a href="/2014/options?L=33742&W=1&O=06&F=0000"></a>
     | 
    <a href="/2014/options?L=33742&W=2&O=06&F=0000"></a>
     | 
    <a href="/2014/options?L=33742&W=3&O=06&F=0000"></a>
     | 
    <a href="/2014/options?L=33742&W=4&O=06&F=0000"></a>
     | 
    <a href="/2014/options?L=33742&W=5&O=06&F=0000"></a>
     | 
    <a href="/2014/options?L=33742&W=6&O=06&F=0000"></a>
     | 
    <a href="/2014/options?L=33742&W=7&O=06&F=0000"></a>
</span>
```

Comment: Java? You mean JavaScript right? What have you tried?

Comment: using a simple Regex and jquery is easy to handle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.reportnavigation').contents().filter(function() {
     return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) === '|';
}).remove();
```

Comment: +1 since this is only approach that won't interfere with any possible events bound to elements

Answer (score 1):

I see you got quite a few JavaScript solutions but replacing the HTML using JavaScript will require to reinitialize any events bound on the elements, e.g. click events on the `<a>` elements (except the solution @undefined posted).

You cannot remove it using CSS, you can only hide it. The trick is to use `font-size:0;` and this will make the characters not visible. You need also to add an extra rule so that the child elements of this `<span>` will have a font size bigger than 0.

Also, some extra adjustments might be required, depending the page's existing CSS.

```
.reportnavigation {font-size:0;}
.reportnavigation * {font-size:12px;}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76wtR/1/

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can use a regular expression to replace it:

```
$('.reportnavigation').html($('.reportnavigation').html().replace(/\|/g,''));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tzar/)

Answer (score 0):

What about a Pure CSS solution?

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dcjAC)**

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}
a + a {
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: -0.43em;
}
a {
  margin-right: 20px; /* whatever value you want */
}
```

This `-0.43em` value is borrowed from Yahoo! Pure CSS framework: http://blog.purecss.io/post/60789414532/how-we-improved-grids-in-pure-0-3-0
That's equivalent to 4px - width of a whitespace - except more compatible. It solves (in CSS) the problem of 4px gap between blocks displayed as inline-block and can be adapted here to hide a character by superimposing the next one on it.

Comment: I notice a strange behavior in Firefox. In a 949x981 window with a 935x834 viewport the whole HTML fits in 3 lines. In the end of the second line, the `|` character is visible. The same happens in Chrome, but in a window that is a bit smaller in width.